# Mouse cursor spinning forever after startup

Tags: 11.10, mouse, cursor

After startup, the mouse cursor keeps spinning...

This doesn't happen every time but at 50% of times. After a relog it works as espected.

This is very annoying. How can I fix this? Anyone else having this issue?

Please i don't want to login twice every time.

ps. Autologin is active

Comment: What graphics card do you have ? What driver are you using ? Does it persist if you disable autologin ? You can try adding `console=tty1` to your boot parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing ctrl alt del, then go to task manager, then open processes.

Watch the running programs and watch the cursor.

When the cursor spins one of the programs running will switch on in the running processes list and when the cursor stops spinning the program will disappear from the running processes list.

In my case it's the HP wireless printer which goes on and off in the running processes list.

I don't know a workround but this method might show you what is causing the annoyance.

Regards and good luck

Norman

Comment: Ctrl+alt+DEL? Task manager??? Are you even talking about Ubuntu?

Comment: That's Windows, bro. We are talking about Ubuntu.